# Help with installing/dual booting Windows 10 on a Ubuntu laptop?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 15.10, windows-10

I was wondering if anyone could help me with on how to install/dualboot a Windows 10 on a laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad T450s) that is currently running on Ubuntu 15.10?

I recently uninstalled my Windows 10 on my laptop to run ubuntu 15.10. I sort of need to reinstall windows 10 but am unsure on how to do so. I can't seem to do it by making a bootable flash drive since whenever I try to run it, bios doesn't detect the bootable device properly.

I tried the instructions on this link ([How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)) but I always seem to get stuck on the installing windows part (since I'm installing windows 10 and not 7). Any ideas on how to proceed would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was easier to install Ubuntu after windows. Install Windows with the needed partition space you specify, then run the Ubuntu installer via bootable USB. Ubuntu will see the unpartitioned space. You can then install there. With this, you will need to boot into Ubuntu using the F9 option at BIOS boot so you can boot Ubuntu.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I tend to agree, you need to always install Windows _then_ install Linux, for a dual boot system. Often Microsoft's install process will wipe your boot sector and possibly remove things like GRUB (it has for me in the past), resulting in a major PITA recovering access to the Linux system on the drive.

Comment: Yes, I agree but in my current situation I only have ubuntu installed and it's not allowing me to install windows 10 from the bios. Whenever I keep trying to boot from the flash drive, it keeps sending me back to the bios.

Comment: Can you tell me on how to uninstall ubuntu completely and have only windows 10 running then? Dual booting a windows machine with linux is far easier in my expereince but I'm kind of lost on how to proceed at the moment.

Comment: Run the windows installer buy via bootable USB or CD and  after you accept the terms of conditions the next screen select Custom this will show you all the current partitions. Select a partition and choose Delete. Do this until all the partitions are deleted and you only show one unallocated space. At this point select the unallocated space and click the button that says new. Choose a partition size then click Next. This will install Windows on the allocated space that you specified. Once you install windows and it is completed then you can install Ubuntu.

Comment: If drive is MBR & you are booting Ubuntu in BIOS mode, you need a primary NTFS partition with the boot flag for Windows to install into. Or enough unallocated space. It normally wants two primary partitions one is just Boot partition, but will install to one. It will not see Linux partitions and if Linux partition is a logical, it may not include that when it rewrites partition table. Make sure you have good backups & a backup of partition table structure after you have resized everything.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll try allocating more space. Hopefully that will fix it.