# Boot Windows from USB on an Ubuntu laptop

Tags: boot, usb

I have laptop which from the beginning running Windows 8, I later wiped the hard-drive and installed Ubuntu 14.04. Now I want to wipe the hard-drive and install Windows 10. In BIOS I have selected to boot from USB. But whenever I boot my computer it does **not** boot on the USB, it just starts Ubuntu. What can I do about it?

I downloaded the `.iso` file from Microsoft. Then I used Rufus to put it to my USB

[image]

I have also tried the following in Rufus which ended in an error message

```
""The file system currently selected can not be used with this type of ISO. PLease select a different file system or use a different ISO"
```

[image]

I have looked at these three questions, but I did not find them helpful.

[Ubuntu not booting from USB on laptop (no optical drive)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161328/ubuntu-not-booting-from-usb-on-laptop-no-optical-drive)

[Help with installing/dual booting Windows 10 on a Ubuntu laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698034/help-with-installing-dual-booting-windows-10-on-a-ubuntu-laptop)

[How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

**Solution**
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/

Comment: How did you create the bootable USB stick?

Comment: I have made an edit, @NickWeinberg

Comment: Thanks for all the effort @Dhibi.H I managed to find a solution via microsofts homepage.

Comment: Please do not put `SOLVED` in the title, just check the check-mark onto the answer which was most helpful for you. Thank you.

Comment: It is not a duplicate as I was not able to boot on the USB. @Pilot6

Comment: In this case it is off-topic as not related to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

after you press the power button , you hold the "esc" key down.
than it will show you options either to start from the usb stick or the hard disk , you choose to start on the usb stick and it will run perfectly.
there is no problem with the version of Rufus you just create the boot stick  with the default settings and it will be fine.

Comment: There is no usb option

Comment: only two different ubuntu options

Comment: what are they?try test them.

Comment: At first i have *System information *System Diagnostics *Boot Device Options *bios setup *System Recovery. Then I choose *Boot Device Options. And I get *Ubuntu (ST500LM012 HN-M500MBB) *ubuntu (ST500LM012 HN-M500MBB) *Boot from EFI File... When I try the first the normal Ubuntu log in appears. When I choose the second one, the normal ubuntu log in screen appears, (same as previous). When I choose the third the following appears *NO VOLUME LABEL, [Acpi(PNP0A03,0)/Pci(1FI2)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(Part1,Sig9C03705A-9F00-4296-8E7F-0E85A456C240)]

Comment: I mounted Ubuntu 16.04 on the same usb stick, and it booted correctly the first time? Could there be something wrong with the windows iso file I am using? @Dhibi.h

Comment: I downloaded the iso from microsoft via my university.

Comment: try to set the file system in Rufus FAT32

Comment: Got an error msg "The file system currently selected can not be used with this type of ISO. PLease select a different file system or use a different ISO. I posted, look at the question, a picture showing what I choosed in rufus. @Dhibi.H

Comment: I noticed that when I mount the Ubuntu ISO, it sets to FAT32 automaticly, with no error. Maybe I should try another W iso. @Dhibi.H

Comment: maybe it is a problem with the iso but if you still get the same problem i think you should try to delete all the partitions with gparted after booting from an ubuntu usb  and reinstall windows